# Difference between "Preview" and Query in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following table schema:

```
+-----+---------+----------+
+ chn | INTEGER | NULLABLE |
+-----+---------+----------| 
+ size| STRING  | NULLABLE |
+-----+---------+----------| 
+ char| REPEATED| NULLABLE |
+-----+---------+----------| 
+ ped | INTEGER | NULLABLE |
+-----+---------+----------
```

When I click on 'preview' in the Google BigQuery Web UI, I get the following result:

[image]

But when I query my table, I get this result:

[image]

It seems like "preview" is interpreting my repeated field as an array, I would want to get the same result in a query to limit the number of rows.

I **did** try to uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" which gave me the same result but the problem is that with my table, a same query takes ~1.0 sec to execute with "Use Legacy SQL" checked and ~12 seconds when it's unchecked.

I am looking for speed here so unfortunately, not using Legacy SQL is not an option...

Is there another way to render my repeated field like it does in the "preview" ?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Do you have a job ID for executions of the query with and without "Use Legacy SQL" checked? We're very interested in any performance discrepancies and would like to resolve whatever the issue is as soon as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In legacy SQL, BigQuery flattens the result of queries by default. This means two things:

1. All child fields of `RECORD` fields are propagated to the top-level, with their names changed from `record.subrecord.leaf` to `record_subrecord_leaf`.  Parent records are removed from the schema.
2. All repeated fields are converted to fields of optional mode, with each repeated value expanded into its own row.  (As a side note, this step is very similar to the [`FLATTEN`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#flatten) function exposed in legacy SQL.)

What you see here is a product of #2.  Each repeated value is becoming its own row (as you can see by the row count on the left-hand side in your two images) and the values from the other columns are, well, repeated for each new row.

You can prevent this behavior and receive "unflattened results" in a couple ways.

1. Using standard SQL, as you note in your original question.  All standard SQL queries return unflattened results.
2. While using legacy SQL, setting the `flattenResults` parameter to false.  This requires also specifying a destination table and setting `allowLargeResults` to false.  These can be found in the `Show Options` panel beneath the query editor if you want to set them within the UI.  Mikhail has some good suggestions for managing the temporary-ness of destination tables if you aren't interested in keeping them around.

I should note that there are a number of corner cases with legacy SQL with `flattenResults` set to false which might trip you up if you start writing more complex queries.  A prominent example is that you can't output more than one independently repeated field in query results using legacy SQL, but you can output multiple with standard SQL.  These issues are unlikely to be resolved in legacy SQL, and going forward we're suggesting people use standard SQL when they run into them.

If you could provide more details about your much slower query using standard SQL (e.g. job ID in legacy SQL, job ID in standard SQL, for comparison), I, and the rest of the BigQuery team, would be very interested in investigating further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would gladly use Standard SQL if it was not so slow...

For example, the same query using:

Legacy SQL: 7b3a2309_156d55bab07 (4.0s)

Standard SQL: 420aee62_156d55ba2d0 (8.8s)

Comment: Hi, I looked into the slowness on your behalf: You've hit a particular corner case with the combination of small queries + EU data. We're aware of the problem and looking into improvements, but it's not isolated to Standard SQL. You may see the slower behavior if your specify a destination table for your Legacy SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there another way to render my repeated field like it does in the
>   "preview" ?

To see original not-flattened output in Web UI for Legacy SQL, i used to set respective options (click <kbd>Show Options</kbd>) to actually write output to table with checked `Allow Large Results` and unchecked `Flatten Results`.
This actually not only saves result into table but also shows result in the same way as preview does (because it is actually preview of that table). To make sure that table gets removed afterwards - i have "dedicated" dataset (temp) with default expiration set to 1 day (or hour - depends on how aggressive you want to be with your junk), so you don't need to worry of that table(s)  - it will get deleted automatically for you.  Wanted to note: this was quite a common pattern for us to deal with and having to do extra settings was boring, so we ended up with our own custom UI that does all this for user automatically

Answer (score 1):

What you see is called `Flatten`.

By default the UI flattens the query output, there is currently no option to show query results like you want. In order to produce unflatten results you must write to a table, but that's different thing.